# scipy Multinomial pmf return nan

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, multinomial

I'm trying to use the `multinominal.pmf` function from `scipy.stats` (python).

When I use this function where all probabilities in the input bigger than zero, it work fine. The problem is when I want to use the function when one of the probabilities is zero.

The following example shows what I mean:

```
In [18]: multinomial.pmf([3, 3, 0], 6, [1/3.0, 1/3.0, 1/3.0])
Out[18]: 0.027434842249657095

In [19]: multinomial.pmf([3, 3, 0], 6, [2/3.0, 1/3.0, 0])
Out[19]: nan
```

As can be seen, in the first time where all probabilities > 0 there is no problem to use the function. However when I change one of the probabilities to zero, the function return `nan`, even through the function should return `0.21948`.

Is there a way (in python) to calculate the pmf when one of the probabilities is zero? either another way that can handle it, or a work around for this function.

**additional info**

The value that the function in the example should have returned I calculated using mnpdf function in matlab. However since the rest of my code is in python I prefer to find a way to calculate it in python.

Comment: That looks like a bug.  Could you create an issue for this over at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?  (Click the green "New issue" button.)

Comment: Yes, I will do it now.

Answer (score 6):

Good spot! This is a bug in scipy. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py).

Line 3031 to 3051:

```
def pmf(self, x, n, p):
    return np.exp(self.logpmf(x, n, p))
```

Line 2997 to 3017:

```
def logpmf(self, x, n, p):
    n, p, npcond = self._process_parameters(n, p)
```

Line 2939 to 2958:

```
def _process_parameters(self, n, p):

    p = np.array(p, dtype=np.float64, copy=True)
    p[...,-1] = 1. - p[...,:-1].sum(axis=-1)

    # true for bad p
    pcond = np.any(p <= 0, axis=-1)  # <- Here is why!!!
    pcond |= np.any(p > 1, axis=-1)

    n = np.array(n, dtype=np.int, copy=True)

    # true for bad n
    ncond = n <= 0

    return n, p, ncond | pcond
```

The line `pcond = np.any(p <= 0, axis=-1)` results in `pcond` being `true` if any value of `p` is <= 0.

Then in `logpmf` line 3029:

```
return self._checkresult(result, npcond_, np.NAN)
```

results in `logpmf` and `pmf` returning `nan`!

Note that the actual result is calculated properly (line 3020, 2994-2995):

```
result = self._logpmf(x, n, p)

def _logpmf(self, x, n, p):
    return gammaln(n+1) + np.sum(xlogy(x, p) - gammaln(x+1), axis=-1)
```

With your values:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import xlogy, gammaln

x = np.array([3, 3, 0])
n = 6
p = np.array([2/3.0, 1/3.0, 0])

result = np.exp(gammaln(n+1) + np.sum(xlogy(x, p) - gammaln(x+1), axis=-1))
print(result)

>>>0.219478737997
```

Comment: Great analysis.  If you have a moment, could you add this information to the [scipy issue that @rfire created](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8235)?